# SQL double comparison

Tags: sql, comparison, double

let's say I have following SQL column:

[image: SQL table]

Now, I want to do following:
In col_1, I have the value 'one'. If I check, which corresponding values I get in col_2 I get for that, I find 'two' and 'three'. So the results would be 'two' and 'three'. But from this result set, I want to only have those, that, used in `col_1`, have, in col_2, the corresponding value 'one'. So:
'two', in `col_1`, *does* have 'one' in `col_2`, but three doesn't. So, from the result set of {'two', 'three'} only {'two'} would remain.

How can I make such a double-checking query with MySQL?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done by `JOIN`ing a table to itself with a given condition. Assuming your table name is `table`:

```
SELECT t1.col_1
FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.col_2=t2.col_1
WHERE t1.col_1=t2.col_2 
AND t1.col_1='one';
```

This gives:

```
 col_1 
-------
 one
(1 row)
```

Comment: This returns an error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.col_2=t2.col_1 WHERE t1.col_1=t2.col_2 AND t1.col_' at line 2

Comment: Change `table` to your actual table name.

Comment: :D I did ^^ I even, to be absolutely sure, had created a table called `table` with the actual column names used here, the very reproduction of the given example, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Oh, now I know what's wrong: it must be `table`, not table. (With the ` sign) Table is probably a reserved name.