# How would I perform this MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have a table called "approvals".

```
mysql> desc approval;
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| to_user_id  | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Let's say Jessica approves Matt.  Jessica would be the `user_id`, and Matt would be the `to_user_id`.

How do I run this query?

```
SELECT * WHERE to_user_id = matt AND matt also approved that person ?
```

(in other words, if Jessica approves Matt, but Matt doesn't approve Jessica, then the query wouldn't show up.)

Comment: I've asked that question already ^^
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611125/sql-double-comparison

Answer (score 3):

try (corrected according to comments)

```
SELECT * 
FROM approvals A 
INNER JOIN approvals B 
ON A.user_id = B.to_user_id AND B.user_id = A.to_user_id 
WHERE A.to_user_id = matt
```

Comment: This would return a result if Jessica approves Matt but Matt doesn't approve Jessica

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly,

```
select * from approvals a1 join approvals a2 where a1.user_id=a2.to_user_id and a2.user_id=a1.to_user_id
```

I think.

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes I modified your table to use varchars for the user id's but ints will work the same way.

Because of this requirement

> if Jessica approves Matt, but Matt doesn't approve Jessica, then the query wouldn't show up

You need to do a self join on the ID's twice not once. Other wise Eeyore would show up in your results.

```
CREATE approvals table (id int, user_id varchar(10), to_user_id varchar(10))
INSERT INTO 
approvals
VALUES ( 1 , 'Matt' , 'Jessica' ),
( 2 , 'Jessica' , 'Matt' ),
( 3 , 'Eeyore' , 'Jessica' ),
( 4 , 'Eeyore' , 'Matt' )

SELECT * 
FROM   approvals a 
       INNER JOIN approvals b 
         ON a.user_id = b.to_user_id 
            AND b.user_id = a.to_user_id 
WHERE  a.to_user_id = 'Matt'
```

You can see this in action at this [Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2161/sample-for-8274855)